# doubts about C pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to understand basic concepts in C. I have two questions :

1.Why will the following piece of code work and the other does not?

```
/* This works fine */
typedef int SortTableRows[20]; 

SortTableRows* SortTableRowsPtr;

/* This will give error --> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer*/
int SortTableRows[20]; 

SortTableRows* SortTableRowsPtr;
```

1. Second question is what is the third line of code doing?

   ```
   typedef int SortTableRows[20]; 

   SortTableRows* SortTableRowsPtr;

   SortTableRowsPtr[2][3]=2; //Why the compiler doesnt give any error?how can we use a     pointer as a 2d array.
   ```

Comment: You're trying to use `SortTableRows` as both a type name and as a variable name; of course you're going to run into difficulties ;)

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: I have not written any C in oh, about 20 years, but pointers and arrays were mostly interchangeable. So referring to the 3 row of the 2nd column (or however you want to call it) is not a syntax error -- just unusual and probably confusing.

Comment: In this statement `typedef int SortTableRows[20];`, `SortTableRows` becomes an identifier. What would be the interpretation of `SortTableRows* SortTableRowsPtr`. Would it be `int* SortTableRowsPtr` ? Is there any significance to `[20]` in the type declaration statement?

Comment: @Ganesh: yes, defining `SortTableRows* SortTableRowsPtr;` makes pointer arithmetic possible - as size of the element that `SortTableRowsPtr` points to is known (`sizeof(int[20])` in this case). And keep in mind that `a[n]`, `*(a + n)` and even `n[a]` (no kidding) mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined `SortTableRows` to be an array of `ints` with `int SortTableRows[20]`. That identifier is now fixed as an array, it cannot be used for anything else. You're then trying to use it as a type to declare a pointer (I think). If you want to declare a pointer to an array of ints you would do it like this:

```
int *SortTableRowsPtr;
SortTablesRowPtr = SortTablesRows;
```

In the second question, you're assigning a value to a pointer to a pointer that you're treating as a two dimensional array, which makes no real difference to your compiler (though it makes no real sense in this context), as 'multidimensional' arrays are stored in memory in a linear way, the same as single dimension arrays. Your `typedef` doesn't make any real sense here, as you're defining a type of array, then making an uninitialised pointer to it (this creates an `int **`), and accessing it as if it points to something valid (which will compile, but would surely crash).

To have this work you'd need to define an array of 20 ints and then point to it:

```
SortTablesRows table[10] = {};  // equivalent to int table[10][20];
SortTablesRowPtr = table;
```

This works because you're declaring a pointer to an array of 20 ints, i.e.

```
int (*SortTablesRowPtr)[20];
```

I've expanded this answer. It helps to explain it more simply step by step. Take a table of 3 rows and 10 columns. That's defined:

```
int table[3][10];
```

You can then set a pointer to this table. Because it's in two dimensions this isn't right:

```
int *ptr = table; // wrong - incompatible pointer
```

But this would point to the second row (and the first column):

```
int *ptr = table[1];
```

In other words you want a pointer to an array of 10 ints, i.e. you want a pointer that points to a type of `int n[10]`. To do this you can write:

```
int (*ptr2)[10] = table;
```

Now you can use `ptr2` to access the table directly, either as pointers, arrays, or both. As it stands it points to the first row and first column. If you add one to `ptr2` it will select the next row.

```
ptr2[1][3] = 3;  // change row 2, column 4
(*(ptr2 + 1))[4] = 10 // row 2, column 5 (yuck)
```

Comment: You are wrong when you say that `int *ptr = table` won't work. It works perfectly and `ptr` points to the first element of the memory allocated for the array. However there is now even less information that this is an array. It has been degraded to a pointer. The real crux is how much information the compiler has when it decides the type and how to handle pointer arithmetic. I usually try to think of an array as a piece of contiguous allocated memory starting at the address of the first element. Trying to think of it any other way will quickly lead to confusion and bugs.

Comment: @AxelOmega: By it won't work I mean in this context; `int *ptr = table` will compile, but it's not a compatible pointer type and would be incorrect if you want to access the table in any meaningful way.

Comment: It that sense it is correct. However you can still access it in a sensible way using `ptr[row*10+col]`. Multidimensional arrays in C is tricky in this sense. That is what I mean by always thinking of arrays as a piece of allocated memory. It gets easier to think that way when you pass arrays as arguments to functions also.

Comment: @AxelOmega: I know what you mean, but you should cast it if you wanted to access it that way (at least to get rid of compiler warnings) - `int *p = (int *) table`

Answer (score 3):

Question 1.

In the first you are telling it that SortTablesRow is an array of 20 ints.  So SortTablesRow is a type.  In the second you are creating a variable called SortTablesRow which is an array of 20 ints.  This can't be used as a type because its a variable.

Question 2.

Here you are typedef'ing SortTablesRow to be an array of 20 ints.  You then say SortTablesRowPtr is a pointer to it.  So now you have a pointer to an array of 20 ints.  This is essentially an int**.  So the first array index is indexing the first pointer and the second array index is indexing the second pointer (or the array) and thus looking up in the 20 element int array.

Comment: Isn't `x` of `int**` type? The code from original question is perfectly fine - `SortTableRowsPtr` is equivalent to `int**`. First dereference moves the pointer by `2 * sizeof(SortTableRows)` and gives   `SortTableRows ` which is equivalent to `int*`.

Comment: Behaviour in the second part of the question is perfectly defined, and would work as long as `SortTableRowsPtr` is initialised to something that's really `SortTableRows[]`.

Comment: @CodePainters:  Very good points, that will teach me to post before going to bed ;)